# Querying MySQL, duration increases 10x fold after adding one more Join

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have a somewhat complicated query consisting of many joins on an issue tracker/project management database in MySQL. 
My issue is that my query was doing OK while I was in the process of building it up, but after the addition of one final join, the query performance (duration) is no longer tolerable.

The query below ran fine with a duration of ~15 seconds, which is acceptable...

```
SELECT distinct p.name, (i_A.hours + i_B.hours + i_C.hours),
    (COALESCE(cv_db2_A.value,0) + COALESCE(cv_db2_B.value,0) + COALESCE(cv_db2_C.value,0)),
    (COALESCE(cv_db3_A.value,0) + COALESCE(cv_db3_B.value,0) + COALESCE(cv_db3_C.value,0)),
    i_A.hours, if (cv_db2_A.value='',NULL,cv_db2_A.value), if (cv_db3_A.value='',NULL,cv_db3_A.value),
    i_B.hours, if (cv_db2_B.value='',NULL,cv_db2_B.value), if (cv_db3_B.value='',NULL,cv_db3_B.value),
    i_C.hours, if (cv_db2_C.value='',NULL,cv_db2_C.value), if (cv_db3_C.value='',NULL,cv_db3_C.value),
    i_date.due_date
    FROM projects p, issues i_team_1, issue_statuses ist, 
        issues i_A, issues i_B, issues i_C, 
        custom_values cv_db2_A, custom_values cv_db3_A, 
        custom_values cv_db2_B, custom_values cv_db3_B,
        custom_values cv_db2_C, custom_values cv_db3_C,
        issues i_date
    WHERE i_date.project_id = p.id and
        ist.id = i_team_1.status_id and 
        i_team_1.project_id = p.id and
        i_team_1.tracker_id = 23 and i_team_1.subject like 'Group1' and
        i_A.project_id = p.id and i_B.project_id = p.id and i_C.project_id = p.id and
        i_A.subject = 'A Hours' and i_B.subject = 'B Hours' and i_C.subject = 'C Hours' and 
        cv_db2_A.custom_field_id = 172 and cv_db2_A.customized_id = i_A.id and 
        cv_db3_A.custom_field_id = 173 and cv_db3_A.customized_id = i_A.id and 
        cv_db2_B.custom_field_id = 172 and cv_db2_B.customized_id = i_B.id and 
        cv_db3_B.custom_field_id = 173 and cv_db3_B.customized_id = i_B.id and
        cv_db2_C.custom_field_id = 172 and cv_db2_C.customized_id = i_C.id and 
        cv_db3_C.custom_field_id = 173 and cv_db3_C.customized_id = i_C.id and
        i_date.tracker_id = 4 and i_date.subject like 'Date' and
        i_date.due_date BETWEEN CAST('2014-01-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2014-12-11' AS DATE) and
        p.name NOT LIKE '# Temp%';
```

I then proceeded to add one more join into the mix by: 
adding in one more "**issues i_team_2**" and 3 related "WHERE" conditions.

```
SELECT p.name, (i_A.hours + i_B.hours + i_C.hours),
    (COALESCE(cv_db2_A.value,0) + COALESCE(cv_db2_B.value,0) + COALESCE(cv_db2_C.value,0)),
    (COALESCE(cv_db3_A.value,0) + COALESCE(cv_db3_B.value,0) + COALESCE(cv_db3_C.value,0)),
    i_A.hours, if (cv_db2_A.value='',NULL,cv_db2_A.value), if (cv_db3_A.value='',NULL,cv_db3_A.value),
    i_B.hours, if (cv_db2_B.value='',NULL,cv_db2_B.value), if (cv_db3_B.value='',NULL,cv_db3_B.value),
    i_C.hours, if (cv_db2_C.value='',NULL,cv_db2_C.value), if (cv_db3_C.value='',NULL,cv_db3_C.value),
    i_date.due_date
    FROM projects p, issues i_team_1, issues i_team_2, issue_statuses ist, 
        issues i_A, issues i_B, issues i_C, 
        custom_values cv_db2_A, custom_values cv_db3_A, 
        custom_values cv_db2_B, custom_values cv_db3_B,
        custom_values cv_db2_C, custom_values cv_db3_C,
        issues i_date
    WHERE i_date.project_id = p.id and
        ist.id = i_team_1.status_id and 
        i_team_1.project_id = p.id and i_team_2.project_id = p.id and 
        i_team_1.tracker_id = 23 and i_team_1.subject like 'Group1' and
        i_team_2.tracker_id = 23 and i_team_2.subject like 'Group2' and
        i_A.project_id = p.id and i_B.project_id = p.id and i_C.project_id = p.id and
        i_A.subject = 'A Hours' and i_B.subject = 'B Hours' and i_C.subject = 'C Hours' and 
        cv_db2_A.custom_field_id = 172 and cv_db2_A.customized_id = i_A.id and 
        cv_db3_A.custom_field_id = 173 and cv_db3_A.customized_id = i_A.id and 
        cv_db2_B.custom_field_id = 172 and cv_db2_B.customized_id = i_B.id and 
        cv_db3_B.custom_field_id = 173 and cv_db3_B.customized_id = i_B.id and
        cv_db2_C.custom_field_id = 172 and cv_db2_C.customized_id = i_C.id and 
        cv_db3_C.custom_field_id = 173 and cv_db3_C.customized_id = i_C.id and
        i_date.tracker_id = 4 and i_date.subject like 'Date' and
        i_date.due_date BETWEEN CAST('2014-01-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2014-12-11' AS DATE) and
        p.name NOT LIKE '# Temp%';
```

This one additional join causes my query time to increase 10x from ~15 seconds to ~160 seconds.

- I have tried omitting the "WHERE" conditions for "i_team_2" and it made the query time go down to about ~110 seconds... which is still not acceptable.

---

The **EXPLAIN** function shows 14 "SIMPLE" select type actions. Each one is using an index/key and the number of rows checked for each action does not show a number higher than 150 for any of them.

```
    EXPLAIN: BEFORE
id  select_type table       type    possible_keys                                                           key                                     key_len ref                     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      cv_db3_A    ref     index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id                                  index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id  4       const                   163     Using temporary
1   SIMPLE      i_A         eq_ref  PRIMARY,issues_project_id                                               PRIMARY                                 4       cv_db3_A.customized_id  1       Using where
1   SIMPLE      p           eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                                 PRIMARY                                 4       i_A.project_id          1       Using where
1   SIMPLE      i_team_1    ref     issues_project_id,index_issues_on_status_id,index_issues_on_tracker_id  issues_project_id                       4       i_A.project_id          9       Using where
1   SIMPLE      ist         eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                                 PRIMARY                                 4       i_team_1.status_id      1       Using index
1   SIMPLE      cv_db3_B    ref     index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id                                  index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id  4       const                   163 
1   SIMPLE      i_B         eq_ref  PRIMARY,issues_project_id                                               PRIMARY                                 4       cv_db3_B.customized_id  1       Using where
1   SIMPLE      cv_db3_C    ref     index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id                                  index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id  4       const                   163 
1   SIMPLE      i_C         eq_ref  PRIMARY,issues_project_id                                               PRIMARY                                 4       cv_db3_C.customized_id  1       Using where
1   SIMPLE      i_date      ref     issues_project_id,index_issues_on_tracker_id                            issues_project_id                       4       i_A.project_id          9       Using where
1   SIMPLE      cv_db2_A    ref     index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id                                  index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id  4       const                   164     Using where
1   SIMPLE      cv_db2_B    ref     index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id                                  index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id  4       const                   164     Using where
1   SIMPLE      cv_db2_C    ref     index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id                                  index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id  4       const                   164     Using where

    EXPLAIN: AFTER
id  select_type table       type    possible_keys                                                           key                                     key_len ref                     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      cv_db3_A    ref     index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id                                  index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id  4       const                   144     Using temporary
1   SIMPLE      i_A         eq_ref  PRIMARY,issues_project_id                                               PRIMARY                                 4       cv_db3_A.customized_id  1       Using where
1   SIMPLE      p           eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                                 PRIMARY                                 4       i_A.project_id          1       Using where
1   SIMPLE      i_team_1    ref     issues_project_id,index_issues_on_status_id,index_issues_on_tracker_id  issues_project_id                       4       i_A.project_id          10      Using where
1   SIMPLE      ist         eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                                 PRIMARY                                 4       i_team_1.status_id      1       Using index
1   SIMPLE      cv_db3_B    ref     index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id                                  index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id  4       const                   144 
1   SIMPLE      i_B         eq_ref  PRIMARY,issues_project_id                                               PRIMARY                                 4       cv_db3_B.customized_id  1       Using where
1   SIMPLE      cv_db3_C    ref     index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id                                  index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id  4       const                   144 
1   SIMPLE      i_C         eq_ref  PRIMARY,issues_project_id                                               PRIMARY                                 4       cv_db3_C.customized_id  1       Using where
1   SIMPLE      i_team_2    ref     issues_project_id,index_issues_on_tracker_id                            issues_project_id                       4       i_A.project_id          10      Using where
1   SIMPLE      i_date      ref     issues_project_id,index_issues_on_tracker_id                            issues_project_id                       4       i_A.project_id          10      Using where
1   SIMPLE      cv_db2_A    ref     index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id                                  index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id  4       const                   145     Using where; Distinct
1   SIMPLE      cv_db2_B    ref     index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id                                  index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id  4       const                   145     Using where; Distinct
1   SIMPLE      cv_db2_C    ref     index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id                                  index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id  4       const                   145     Using where; Distinct
```

Note: The "BEFORE" EXPLAIN has higher number of rows due to additions to the data and was taken after the "AFTER" EXPLAIN.

---

**The Sense of the Query:**

I am trying to grab information (i.e. kinds of hours worked ("db2" or "db3") divided per subject area/field (3 different fields: "A","B","C")) for particular project types (i.e. "Group1" or "Group2" project types) that has a certain kind of date fall within a given date range.

In this particular query, I am grabbing the 6 different information fields for project types that include both "Group1" and "Group2" only (intersect, not union).

Note: I accidentally forgot to include the actual data/columns I am retrieving in the SELECT statements above (I pasted my debugging version). However, testing with or without that portion has not given me any advantage in performance and, in conclusion, is not where the problem resides.

---

### Question

- Am I doing anything wrong?
- How can I shorten this query's duration to a more manageable amount?
- Should I split the query up?

Comment: Do you have an index on `custom_values (custom_field_id, customized_id)`? What indexes are there on `issues` and on `projects`? Adding the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` outputs of all the tables and the `EXPLAIN` plan would help.

Comment: I'd try adding `...and i_team_1.tracker_id = i_team_2.tracker_id...` to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: custom_values has custom_values_customized & index_custom_values_on_custom_field_id.

Comment: @mustaccio add "i_team_1.tracker_id = i_team_2.tracker_id" and leave my other i_team_2.tracker_id where condition?? or replace the i_team_2.tracker_id condition?

Comment: Do you have the before EXPLAIN plan too?

Comment: Can you briefly explain the sense of query? Why do you perform so massive joining tables with themselves?

Comment: @kondybas sense of query added. different data (with different reqs) all located in the same tables.
e.g. Subject = "Group1" vs Subject = "Group2"

Comment: Is it true that `issues` table contains several rows for each work (one for group, second for hours and third for DB) with different content in the same `subject` field?

Comment: the issues table contains rows, each row has a subject, hours, and other fields that references a specific group/"db"

Comment: Without `CREATE TABLE` scripts, we can't possibly help for this query. There are a lot of things that could be wrong. In general though, EAV designs needs several composite indexes to perform well.

Comment: Just wondering: what is it that you need to see in the create scripts that is not obvious from the given information? the other indices that aren't being used? datatypes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the EXPLAIN and examining the indices did not help me (maybe I did not try hard (or correctly) enough).

My final solution was to not JOIN together so many instances of large tables (in this case, the "issues" tables). In effect, I split up the query into two queries and now my querying performance is much less than 1 second.

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten the join criteria `and ist.id = i_team_2.status_id`.

If you had used the modern JOIN syntax this would have stood out like a sore thumb.

Comment: has nothing to do with the performance of the query or my question really so I did not care to correct it (i say this from both assuming and empiracal perspectives, as that table "ist" contains 10 rows).
was actually in the process of taking that join OUT when I ran into my actual problem. thanks.

Comment: as you might or might not be able to guess, I am trying to demonstrate in my question that the ONLY complexity I am adding to the query is the i_team_2 join and how it affects my query, and no other constraints or added complexity.